# Ordenar una LinkedList de enteros en Java sin el metodo .sort

Tags: java, lista, método

Muy buenas a todos, Mi problema es que tengo una LinkedList de enteros, y debo mostrar los valores que se añaden a esta ordenados, independientemente del orden en el que se introduzcan los enteros, mi problema es que no puedo utilizar el método `.sort` por petición del enunciado.

Adjunto el pedazo de código que me lleva de cabeza

```
if(Lista.size()>1){
       int size=Lista.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

                  if(Lista.get(i)> numero){

                      Lista.add(Lista.set(Lista.get(i),numero));

                  }
                  else{
                      Lista.addLast(numero);
                  }

                    for(int j= 0; j<size-1; j++){

                        if(Lista.get(j)>Lista.get(j+1)){
                            int tmp=Lista.get(j+1);
                            int tmp2=Lista.get(j+1);
                            int auxilio=Lista.get(j);
                            auxilio= tmp2;
                            tmp2=tmp;
                            Lista.add(Lista.set(Lista.get(j), tmp));

                            if(Lista.get(i)== Lista.get(i+1)){
                            Lista.remove(Lista.get(i));
                            }

                            break;
                          }


                       }
                   }

              }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la solución mas sencilla a mi problema

Lo que hago es volcar el contenido de mi LinkedList principal en una HashSet, Limpiar la Lista principal y volver a volcar el contenido de la HashSet en la LinkedList principal

```
if(Lista.size()>1){
            int size=Lista.size();

              for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

                Lista.add(Lista.set(Lista.get(i),numero));

                   TreeSet<Integer> hs = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                                        hs.addAll(Lista);
                                        Lista.clear();
                                        Lista.addAll(hs);
                                        break;



                                 }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría sería crearme una lista auxiliar que sea exactamente igual que la que tienes y otra del mismo tamaño que sean los resultados y comparar posición por posición una a una.

```
List<Integer> listaOriginal;
List<Integer> listaOriginalAux = listaOriginal;
List<Integer> result;

for(int i = 0; i<listaOriginal.size(); i++){

  int aux = i;
  for(int j = 0; j<listaOriginalAux.size(); j++){

    if(aux<j)
     aux = j;
  }
 result.add(aux);
}
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte o darte alguna idea.

Un saludo!